# A submit button to send data from one php function to another

Tags: php, forms, submit

I'm trying to figure out how to send data from one php function to another through using a submit button. The idea is that a spellchecker will highlight the correct spelling for a word, and the user will click the button to run the program again with the correct spelling.

```
<form method="post" action="results.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Search!" name="submit" id="searchButton" 
           value="<?php
                      $search = "dog";
                      $_POST[$search]
                  ?>"
    />
```

This is what I have so far...

Also, is it possible for the value of a button to be a variable?

Comment: how can you assign multiple values to a single input field?

Comment: Are you essentially trying to get this page to post to its self?

Comment: @ Aaron. Essentially yes. So in the example above I have a string "dog". So if the user clicks the button it will input "dog" into the code from the begining.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden variables as an alternative to ajax.

```
<input type="hidden" value="dog"  id="search" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```